# Is there any way to type a field as a result of string manipulation?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

So I'm in an environment where stuff is sometimes referred to in `camelCase` and other times in `snake_case`. In an effort to start normalizing this, I've written a `getField` helper which first checks for `camelCase`, then `snake_case`. Is there any way I can use `$PropertyType` to get the type I expect in both cases?

```
function toSnakeCase(str: string): string {
  return str.replace(/[A-Z]/g, m => `_${m.toLowerCase()}`);
}

function getField<T: {}>(obj: T, field: string) {
   return obj[field] || obj[toSnakeCase(field)];
}

// this seems to be typed as `any`, which I don't really understand
(getField({a: true}, 'a'): string); // no error
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question correctly.

But you can try  [$ElementType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype), it's the same as `$PropertyType`, but allows any `K`, not string only. So you can add `TFieldName` generic, i.e.:

```
function getField<T: {}, TFieldName: $Keys<T>>(obj: T, field: $Keys<T>): $ElementType<T, TFieldName> {
   return obj[field] || obj[toSnakeCase(field)];
}

// camelCase type
type User = {
    firstName: string,
};

// snake_case type
type UserSK = {
    first_name: string,
}

// firstName is string
const firstName = (getField<User & UserSk, 'firstName'>({firstName: 'Lyle' }, 'firstName'));
```

If you leave just one type - i.e. `camelCase` - then flow respond an error if the method is called for `snake_case` so it can help you to move your project to only one approach.

[try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQoWgC4E8AOBTUBVAZxwCdQBeUAb2VRUgEsTC0A5AQwFscAuUFkgwB2AcwA0tOgCM+NOnQDGfAcPGTUAX3UaA3OsSJIAVyEK0DWEPSwAykPYBrHAGF2xABQDlaQaICU3r4i1LQkOGhGJFYCAHRhWNDsCjjuwADaAIIAtABaALrA4qCcFAB8oAAGAPoAJFScMWiwADIIpK4efhoVfnpahiZmFlYi4QBiDDjQACYAPAAqshpioPMTU9Mc3Hw1ANI4GIQLpaXusFIAVnzzK4wbO-uHxwGgNQCi0DjcQmjz2DgLFZrSYzLY4cpyFBhCJRUDnC5pO4zPKgAA+qLhlzSTTsjhcbhSSOmfjyfQMCksLFARmIZEoNAAkIxmGwuLxQABydgciTSWS0BkMpSctA4Fgc7SIfogUDMlhg0AMQj8HyqRAUoRUuWs7gUUDuUZodYzWZEUgrDnasEc04082cq1sjl+XqIIA)

Comment: This answer is certainly useful for its explanation of `$ElementType`, but it doesn't quite address my use case. The basic point of `getField` is to obscure from the programmer whether the field is in `camelCase` or `snakeCase`. I'm pretty sure at this point that this is a Bad Idea, but I'm still curious to see if there's a way to accomplish it.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood, you can create additional `type` i.e. `UserSK` - with snake case fields definitions, and pass `User & UserSK` type into `getField` generic